# Error: failed to upload release. There's been an error parsing your app's info.plist. Ensure you are uploading a valid IPA and try again

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Having this error while running git action for IOS.

"Error: failed to upload release. There's been an error parsing your app's info.plist. Ensure you are uploading a valid IPA and try again."

Trying to distribute flutter app to firebase but only able to distribute apk file but for ios development job is giving me above error.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Following is the .yml used:

build_ios:
name: Build Flutter (iOS)
runs-on: macOS-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- uses: actions/setup-java@v1
with:
java-version: '12.x'
- uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
with:
flutter-version: '2.5.3'
- run: flutter pub get
- run: flutter clean
- run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
- run: cd /Users/runner/work/cicd/cicd/build/ios/iphoneos
- run: ls
- run: mkdir -p /Users/runner/work/cicd/cicd/build/ios/iphoneos/Payload
- run: mv /Users/runner/work/cicd/cicd/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app /Users/runner/work/cicd/cicd/build/ios/iphoneos/Payload
- run: zip -r /Users/runner/work/cicd/cicd/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.ipa /Users/runner/work/cicd/cicd/build/ios/iphoneos/Payload
- run: rm -rf /Users/runner/work/cicd/cicd/build/ios/iphoneos/Payload
- name: Upload iPA
uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
with:
name: ios-build
path: build/ios/iphoneos
beta_ios:
name: Upload iOS Beta to Firebase App Distribution
needs: [ build_ios ]
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- name: set up JDK 1.8
uses: actions/setup-java@v1
with:
java-version: 1.8
- name: Download Artifact
uses: actions/download-artifact@master
with:
name: ios-build
- name: Upload IPA
uses: wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action@v1.0.0
with:
appId: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_IOS_APP_ID }}
token: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
groups: testerIos
file: Runner.ipa